# I need to create the logic for my app to log in 2 files, but it only logs in one

Tags: android, file, logging, error-logging, writetofile

This is the code that I made. The logic behind it, is that I need to log into the first file, untill it reaches a length of 1500000 (1.5mb) and then to log in the second file, and when both are full, to clear the first log file and write in it.

```
 public static void appendLog(String text)
{
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Passenger");
    if (!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdir();
    File logFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Passenger/passenger_log.txt");
    File logFile2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Passenger/passenger_log2.txt");
    if (!logFile.exists())
    {
        try
        {
            logFile.createNewFile();
            logFile2.createNewFile();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try
    {
        if(logFile.length() > 1500000 ) {
            writeTo1 = false;
            writeToLog(text, logFile2);
        }else if (logFile.length() > 1500000  && logFile2.length() > 1500000 ){
            logFile.delete();
            logFile.createNewFile();
            writeTo1 = true;
            writeToLog(text, logFile);
        } else{
            writeTo1 = true;
            writeToLog(text, logFile);
        }
        if(writeTo1 == true && logFile.length() > 800000){
            logFile2.delete();
            logFile2.createNewFile();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is that it only logs in the first file, whats wrong in my logic?

Comment: do you debug the code, what is the output of 'logFile.length()'

Comment: swap position of second condition and first condition. Because, if first condition is not true, then the second condition is also not true, so the third condition will true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed it like this, and now it works:

```
public static void appendLog(String text)
{
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Passenger");
    if (!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdir();
    File logFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Passenger/passenger_log.txt");
    File logFile2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Passenger/passenger_log2.txt");
    if (!logFile.exists())
    {
        try
        {
            logFile.createNewFile();
            logFile2.createNewFile();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        if (logFile.length() > 1500000  && logFile2.length() > 1500000 ){
            logFile.delete();
            logFile.createNewFile();
            writeTo1 = true;
            writeToLog(text, logFile);
        }else if(logFile.length() > 1500000 ) {
            writeTo1 = false;
            writeToLog(text, logFile2);
        } else{
            writeTo1 = true;
            writeToLog(text, logFile);
        }
        if(writeTo1 == true && logFile.length() > 1500000 && logFile2.length() > 1500000){
            logFile2.delete();
            logFile2.createNewFile();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot Vandaics, you were right, I changed those 2, and also after some testing, I managed to make it work perfectly